For credit unions that use JHA Symitar, what value does the customer identifier map to and is that value unique?
I was wondering if the member number/customer identifier OAuth claim is guaranteed to be unique for credit unions that use Banno. As I understand it, a member can have multiple member numbers for different shares/loans and view all those shares/loans on the portal.
I'm working on an application that hinges on the uniqueness of this value to reconcile our data with the customer's data dumps for JHA Symitar CUs since my client prefers not to use SSN.
I read the documentation on the unique customer identifier here https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/ to understand that member number/unique customer identifier are likely the same.
What value does the unique customer identifier/member number in Banno map to in Symitar and what is it's significance?
Also, do non-JHA customers have control of which member number to send to Banno or is there a standard Banno uses?


I was wondering if the member number/customer identifier OAuth claim is guaranteed to be unique for credit unions that use Banno.

The https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier - Unique customer identifier (CIF or Member Number) restricted claim (as described in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) is smart enough to recognize whether this particular instance of Banno is running on a bank or a credit union.

For a bank, it'll return a CIF.
For a credit union, it'll return a Member Number.

The Member Number is unique within a particular financial institution. There are no guarantees about uniqueness across financial institutions.

What value does the unique customer identifier/member number in Banno map to in Symitar and what is it's significance?

If we're talking about the Symitar core and therefore a credit union, the Unique Customer Identifier restricted claim represents a Member Number.

Also, do non-JHA customers have control of which member number to send to Banno or is there a standard Banno uses?

There is no concept of 'sending a Member Number to Banno' via the Banno Digital Toolkit. The Banno Digital Toolkit is only available for Jack Henry-powered financial institutions which use the Banno Digital Platform.

This clarifies a lot, thanks!
What I meant in the last bit was that if a client had a Symitar core where they have multiple memberships and maybe multiple member numbers, which member number would be sent by the Symitar core? Does the financial institution choose which member number to send or is there a default member number that gets chosen?

The enrollment into digital banking narrows things down to a single member number. The member may have more than one member number, but that would mean they would need to enroll in Banno with each individual member number...which means distinctly separate Banno logins for that member.
